# Angular 2 and Cloudkit JS - resolving response promises

Tags: angular, es6-promise, angular2-services, cloudkit-web-services

I'm trying to get Angular 2 work with Cloudkit JS, currently a simple Todo.

**todo.request.js**:

```
var todorequest = {
    get: function(){
        var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
        var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase;

        var query = {
            recordType: 'todo'
        };

        return publicDB.performQuery(query).then(function (response) {
            if(response.hasErrors) {
                throw response.errors[0];
            } else {
                let vals = [];
                response.records.forEach(function(record){
                    vals.push({title: record.fields['title'].value, text: record.fields['text'].value, date: record.fields['date'].value})
                })
                console.log(vals)
                return vals;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This returns `Array [ Object, Object ]` which is what I wanted, all good so far.

**todo.service.ts** has the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo';

declare var todorequest:any;

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

    constructor() {}

    getTodos() {
        return new Promise<Todo[]>(resolve =>
            todorequest.get() as Todo[] 
            );
    }
}
```

I assume what I get from *todorequest.get()* is a promise, such as  `Object { Symbol(record)_1.k31kpejw2af: Object }`. How do I convert it do Todo[], so I will be able to use the data? To be honest I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! I was missing **resolve** in service

```
getTodos() {
        return new Promise<Todo[]>(resolve =>
            resolve(todorequest.get())
            );
    }
```